# Time complexity of these 2 program

Tags: java, string, algorithm, time-complexity

I am new to complexity analysis. The task is that given a non-empty string like "Code" return a string like "CCoCodCode". I have these 2 programs which are doing the same thing.

Program 1:

```
public String stringSplosion(String str) {
    String result = "";
    for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<=i;j++)
            result += str.charAt(j);
    }
    return result;
}
```

So, above one is pretty simple and this program has **O(n^2)** complexity.

Program 2:

```
public String stringSplosion(String str) {
    String result = "";
    // On each iteration, add the substring of the chars 0..i
    for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
        result = result + str.substring(0, i+1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

From a different StackOverflow question, it seems `str.substring()` has a time complexity of **O(n)**. In that case, program 2 also has **O(n^2)** time complexity.

Is my analysis correct or I am missing something?

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: Well even more, you can make it a bit faster (but still O(n^2)) by using a StringBuilder instead of the string concatenation. Btw. all Algorithms solving this problem have at least O(n^2) time complexity since the output has length O(n^2).

Comment: I think you are right. You can always test execution times with really long strings. For example, if you go from length=1000 to length=2000, does execution time increase with a factor 4 for both methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact, both have the same complexity - `O(n^3)`. That's because you're using `+=` for concatenating the answer! there's a hidden loop there that you didn't account for, and a classic example of [Schlemiel the Painter's Algorithm](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/schlemiel_the_painter%27s_algorithm). You should use `StringBuilder` instead, it's the right way to build a string as you go.

Comment: @Stefan Indeed! There's the explicit loop, and the loop in the `substring` operation, and finally the loop in the `+` concatenation operation

Comment: While this is a good observation, the compiler will convert his string concatenation to a StringBuilder internally. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1

Comment: Yes, but not necessarily an useful one. It depends on where it’s declared - inside or outside the loops

Answer (score 0):

Forgive the indentation but this is essentially a solution that satisfies the tests.

```
    public String stringSplosion(String str) {
      // Empty String test
      if (str.length() == 0) 
        return str;

      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

      for (int i=0; i<=str.length() ; i++) {
        sb.append(str.substring(0,i));
      }
      return sb.toString();
   }
```